# Каким методом добавить текст в JTable?

Tags: java

Например в 1 строку, 2 столбец  -  текст "hhhh".

Answer (score 1):

```
javax.swing.table.TableModel.getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
```

Comment: @jMind, мне нужно текст добавить, а не получить

Comment: ну тогда TableModel.setValueAt("hhhh", rowIndex, columnIndex) :)